# Get the status of a python process that was executed in another terminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal, subprocess, popen

I have a python program that will create and execute another python script in a new terminal. To do so, I'm using subprocess.Popen. I'm trying to get the PID of the new process using .pid. However, the value of this pid doesn't seem to match the real pid of the newly created process (the two values don't match).

Here's a sample of my code:

```
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen("gnome-terminal -e 'python'",shell = True)
print p.pid
```

In the newly opened terminal, I try to get the pid using:

```
import os
print os.getpid()
```

I'm getting two different values. Does anyone know how to get the correct pid? I need this to know when the second process has been completed in order to do an action in the first process.

Thanks for your help!

If you need more details, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, the value of this pid doesn't seem to match the real pid of the newly created process (the two values don't match).

There are three processes here: `shell=True` causes `/bin/sh` to run that runs `gnome-terminal` that runs `python` (perhaps indirectly). `gnome-terminal` may be just a starter program that delegates starting `python` to a running server process and exits.

`shell=False` won't help here. You'll get gnome-terminal's pid instead of `/bin/sh`—you won't get `python` process' pid.

You could write the pid in a known file or communicate it via pipe/socket.

Comment: That's true! What I did is that I wrote the pid of the new process in a text file and then I opened that file in the old process to monitor the status of the created terminal. It's a bit complicated but at least it works. How can I do this via pipe/socket? Is it easier?

Comment: @Eliekhalifeh: what to use depends on your use case. If a simple text file works for you (e.g., no risk of a concurrent access when two or more python processes overwrite it before your parent python scripts can read the corresponding pids)  then use it. The code for a named pipe looks almost the same but no data is written to disk (and therefore the pid won't be available if your parent python script dies after reading it). Unix sockets allow to communicate both ways (parent <-> child python scripts). tcp/udp sockets allow to communicate between different machines (e.g., over internet).

Comment: @j-f-sebastian It seems more complicated! The text file I'm creating will be deleted once the parent dies, so no files are kept on the disk. Do you have any link where I can see how unix sockets can be used? Thank you! I will accept your answer since it is more useful than the other!

Comment: @Eliekhalifeh: you could google *unix sockets python* and follow a couple of links to see the examples

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

If you set the shell argument to `True`, this is the process ID of the spawned shell.

So you'll need `shell=False`

Comment: Is there a way to do this with shell = True?

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll accept your answer since it's solved the problem!

Comment: I just tried it. It doesn't seem work with shell=False either!